# cron.sh not working for Magento cron job

Tags: shell, magento, cron

I have been having problems with Magento and cron jobs not running. It seems that certain parameters with cron.sh are not allowed by my hosting company (ps being one of them) therefore the shell script failed before the cron job was run. As my cron in cpanel declares the full path I am wondering if I can remove certain lines from cron.sh eg.

```
#!/bin/sh
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#   prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
#    if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
#    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
#       $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
#    fi
#else
#    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
    $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
#    fi
#fi
```

Does anyone know if this will work and are there any drawbacks/consequences?

Answer (score 2):

Without having particular knowledge of this functionality - it looks like it could be potentially trying to avoid running the cron script again while it's already running. Perhaps the same could be done with a lock file - but this is one area of Magento I wouldn't muck around with without a lot of research.

This is orthogonal to a larger issue, however. Magento is more picky with hosting than the average PHP codebase, and this is probably just the *beginning* of issues you will have with your host. I **strongly** recommend considering a host that is very familiar with Magentos needs. If commenting out chunks of Magento core code becomes the norm - you **will** run into many more issues down the line.